# Does Parse now support more than 1 geopoint per object?

Tags: parse-platform

It used to be, and the documentation still says: Each PFObject class may only have one key with a PFGeoPoint object.

But in my tests today, I created an object with 2 GeoPoint columns, was able to query on either GeoPoint, and was able to modify and save either GeoPoint. Previously, this would lead to an error like: only 1 ParseGeoPoint object can be stored in a class.

Is this really supported now?

Some additional info: I first have to create the 2 geoPoint columns in the data browser. If they don't exist and my iPhone code tries to save an object with 2 geoPoints, then I get the "only one GeoPoint field may exist in an object". But as long as the 2 columns exist, my client code appears to be able to use both.

Answer (score 2):

As of July 2015, Parse still does not support more than one GeoPoint column on a class. They have, however, fixed the Data Browser to prevent users from creating two GeoPoint columns.

Answer (score 1):

Got this response from Parse (in the Google Group forum):

Hmm, that sounds like a problem with the data browser's mechanism of altering the schema. Could you report a bug? I would not recommend using objects created in this way - the underlying data store can only index one geopoint field per object, so whichever field gets indexed second just will have the index fail and you won't be able to run queries against it.

Comment: Here's a link to the thread on Parse's google group forum if anyone is interested in more info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/QF9ri14aULo

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to put the second GeoPoint (which you will not be able to search on) into a singleton array.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: True - thanks.  Parse does support more than one GeoPoint per object, but it only supports one searchable/indexable GeoPoint per object. In order to enforce this, Parse restricts the number of raw GeoPoints (ie. not encompassed in other objects) to one.  Therefore, any method of having multiple GeoPoints isn't the obvious 'pure' method.  The method I choose to use is a singleton array